# How to fix pod: command not found? I have trying many but not yet find the answer?

Tags: cocoapods

I was tried below commands in the terminal:

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/
gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
rbenv global system
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

But it still the same problem... Any ideas about this.

Comment: What version of ruby are you running? Type ruby -v

Comment: here is: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]

Answer (score 9):

The below command work for me.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -V
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [installation guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods)? and you did not mention what pod you want to install. Please provide more information so we can help you.

Comment: What I did after install it:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.5.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.5.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 3 seconds
1 gem installed